# AS3 / Changing the appearance of a button

Tags: actionscript-3

I inherited a project consisting of a flash movie with graphic components and an .as file with the code. i want to alter the appearance of various graphic elements.

example:

`if (skin="client1")` -> all buttons have to be blue, `if (skin="client2")` -> all buttons have to be yellow - and so on.

I am stuck with a button:

1. I tried and nested a movie with different colors (`frame1=blue`, `frame5=yellow`) inside the button, but i can't find a way to `goToAndStop` that movie from the .as file.
2. I tried to check a variable from inside that movie (`if skin="client1" goto frame "blue"`), but I can't seem to get access to the other variables, which are defined inside the .as file.

Answer (score 1):

AS3 is fully Object-Oriented.

If those variable are private or protected you CAN'T access them.

Comment: well, they are mine, so i should be able to do what i want with them ;) the question remains: how i can access (or target) a movie inside of a button or a variable from the movie inside that button.

Comment: You should be able to access it just with the "dot" syntax. It's really difficult to help you without source :(

Comment: understood - but there's such an awful lot of source ;) i tried to access the movie in the button via: "_myMovieMaster.myMovie.ButtonXY.nestedMovie.gotoAndStop(10);" but it didnt work, i even tried to target the states: "_myMovieMaster.myMovie.ButtonXY.upState.nestedMovie.gotoAndStop(10);" but guess what ...

Comment: If that button you target is a SimpleButton, and it has a named asset on the upFrame, you should be able to reach it via `_myMovieMaster.myMovie.ButtonXY.upFrame.nestedMovie`, note that frames are named "upFrame, overFrame, downFrame". In case you can't name an asset on the button, you can either enumerate `upFrame.getChildAt()` from zero to numChildren-1, and evaluate if that asset is what you desire to change (by casting it to a MovieClip for example, if so, calling gotoAndStop() and catch any errors). I had a button like this with an embedded TextField and was able to change it on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Vesper, that was just the idea i needed. i get the object now via `upState.getChildAt(x)` and then apply a `transform.colorTransform`. And strangely it really is "upState".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a two classes to manage the themes:

The first manages the theme name

```
package 
{   
    public class Styles
    {
        public static const DARK:String = "dark";
        public static const LIGHT:String = "light";
        public static var currentStyleName:String = "dark";

        public static function setStyles(styleName:String):void
        {
            currentStyleName = styleName;
        }
    }
}
```

The second one manages the assets

```
package
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;    
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    import Styles;

    public class Assets extends EventDispatcher
    {

        public static function setStyles(styleName:String):void
        {
            currentStyleName = styleName;
        }

        public static function getClass(name:String):Class
        {
            var TheClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(name) as Class;

            return TheClass;
        }

        public static function sprite(name:String):Sprite
        {
            return new (getClass(name)) as Sprite;
        }

        public static function simpleButton(name:String):SimpleButton
        {
            return new (getClass(name)) as SimpleButton;
        }

        public static function styledName(name:String):String
        {
            return name + Styles.currentStyleName.replace(/^\w/, function(firstChar) {
                return firstChar.toUpperCase();
            });
        }

    }
}
```

In your Flash Library you need set the linkage name for each symbol something like this:

```
myButtonDark
myButtonLight
mySpriteDark
mySpriteLight
```

Now you must set the current style name

```
Styles.setStyles(Styles.LIGHT);
```

Finally you can create the instances that you need

```
// All the instances created here belong to the Light theme
addChild( Assets.simpleButton(Assets.styledName("myButton")) );
addChild( Assets.sprite(Assets.styledName("mySprite")) );

// Changes the theme to dark
Styles.setStyles(Styles.DARK);

// All the instances created here belong to the Dark theme
addChild( Assets.simpleButton(Assets.styledName("myButton")) );
addChild( Assets.sprite(Assets.styledName("mySprite")) );
```

I hope that it works for you :)

Comment: Hmmm, very neat - but i would need to build separate buttons for the themes. will keep that in mind for the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since the project is yours, you might provide an additional method to your button to accept a certain change, say, if your nested movie clip has several frames with labels, and you have them arranged for colors like 'blue', 'green', 'black' and so on, you can create a set of skin constants of type String, like Alexander Ruiz suggested, which can also serve as labels for your MCs to switch displayed frame. So, you make a function inside your button class, which can reach your nested movie clip even if it is private, like this:

```
public function AcceptSkin(skin:String):void {
    try {
        nestedMC.gotoAndStop(skin);
    }
    catch(e:Error) {
        trace('Error applying style',skin,e.toString());
    }
}
```

You can do more in such a method. 
Now, when you want all of your buttons go yellow, and you have a "yellow" labeled frame in your MCs (which supposedly contains yellowish appearance for that button), you call `theButton.AcceptSkin('yellow');` for each of the buttons. But if you are using SimpleButton class for your buttons' base class, I'd advise you making your own class for buttons, because SimpleButton class has no easy method of receiving its contents.

Comment: Sadly i am using SimpleButton - won't do that next time ;)